# How to mirror a hash functionality in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I understand that Javascript objects are flexible enough that they can imitate the common hash array functionality (keys as strings, values as primitive types, able to loop by keys/values)...

I have this example and I can't figure out why it doesn't work:

```
var hash = {
 'a' : '',
 'b' : '',
 'c' : '',
}
```

One of those values gets initialized like so:

```
hash['a'] = 5;
```

Then I try to loop through them:

```
var keys = Object.keys(hash);
for(var i in keys){
  console.log(hash[i]);
}
```

The result is 3 'undefined'.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is you're iterating over the keys of the `Object.keys` array (those keys are the integer 0, 1, 2...) and you try to get the property of `hash` using those integers.

You don't need `Object.keys` here :

```
for(var i in hash){
  console.log(hash[i]);
}
```

If you really want to use `Object.keys`, iterate over the elements of the array :

```
var keys = Object.keys(hash);
for(var i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
  console.log(hash[keys[i]]);
}
```

or

```
Object.keys(hash).forEach(function(i){
    console.log(hash[i]);
});
```

Comment: That for..in is that smart, huh?

Comment: `Object.keys` is fine, but if you're iterating using `for` `in` then you ought to guard it with `Object.hasOwnProperty(key)`. If some bozo has added to `Object.prototype` then `hasOwnProperty` will return true only for the keys you assign to the instance.

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't guard against bozos. Adding unnecessary `hasOwnProperty` is bad practice in my opinion. It shows you don't know when it's needed.

Comment: Its not really a protection against 'bozo's, but sometimes you only are interested in properties which are not shared or accessed via prototype chains. So either use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` or indeed check for `.hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: We're talking about an object used as a map and created as a literal, not about some random object.

Comment: Yea in this case it might be unnecessary, but then again the map should be created using `Object.create( null );`.

Comment: @jAndy Did you profile that ? I did for my bounded-cache library. There's no measurable change.

Comment: @dystroy Profile what? I mean, to work really clean and to not worry about properties from some prototype-chains, the object should be a fully self-defined one. Thats only achievable by creating the object with `Object.create( null );`

Comment: In this case, I'm in complete control of that hash so no need for additional checks. What is the advantage of using Object.create instead of hardcoding it?

Comment: @user3046061 It's often touted as a perf improvement because the object is lighter and there's no need to check the prototype for properties (hence why I thought jAndy was meaning that). But it's mostly a protection against other parts of your code which would have added properties to Object.prototype. My opinion is that it's so bad practice to change Object.prototype that you shouldn't bother. You can't guard against coders so crazy : they'll break other things anyway.

Comment: Even if I not fully agree, yes I was a little nitpicking. But again, why don't use the great options which are there :-)

Comment: In any case, there's absolutely no problem in following jAndy's advice and use `Object.create(null);`...

Answer (score 1):

The variable "keys" is not getting initialized with the key values because of what seems to be a **conflict between the variable name "keys" and the function "keys."**

However, if you initialize "keys" as a variable beforehand, and then run the code snippet then it works correct.

Also, if you rename the variable "keys" to anything else then also it works okay.

Below attached screenshot shows the re-enactment of these steps in Chrome Console.

[image: JS Key conflict]

Comment: Nice explanation and it's what I should've done in the first place to track down the error.